# A fair coin tossed repeatedly

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, problem-solving

> A fair coin tossed repeatedly and let $T$ be be the number of tosses till two consecutive tails are observed for the first time.
>
> (a) Show that $E(T|\text{tail is observed in the first toss})=2+\frac{1}{2}E(T)$.
>
> (b) Find similar formula for $E(T|\text{head is observed in the first toss})$.
>
> (c) Compute $E(T)$.

What I can see easily is that

1. The  value we get from (a)+The  value we get from (b)=$E(T)$
2. We let $X_i=1$, if tail occurs, $0$ if head occurs. Then $T|N=n=X_1+X_2+\dots X_n$. But I can not find what $N$ follows!!

Need some hint here!

Comment: For $a$:  what are the possible outcomes of the second toss?  what are the probabilities of each?

Comment: Simplified version of [_this recent question_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329660/binomial-distribution-gamification-for-online-casino/2330870#2330870). See especially answ by @PaulAljabar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathrm t_1, \mathrm t_2$ be the event of a tails in the first and second tosses, respectively, and likewise $\mathrm h_1, \mathrm h_2$ the event of heads in the first and second toss, respectively.

$(a)$ You begin by Law of Total Probability.

$$\mathsf E(T\mid \mathrm t_1) = \mathsf P(\mathrm t_2)\,\mathsf E(T\mid \mathrm t_1, \mathrm t_2) + \mathsf P(\mathrm h_2)\,\mathsf E(T\mid \mathrm t_1, \mathrm h_2)$$

Now you know the coin is fair, that if you have two tails in a row you stop, and if the last toss was a head you count the tries until then and start anew.

Carry on.

---

$(b)$ As above, so below.

$$\mathsf E(T\mid \mathrm h_1) = \mathsf P(\mathrm t_2)\,\mathsf E(T\mid \mathrm h_1, \mathrm t_2) + \mathsf P(\mathrm h_2)\,\mathsf E(T\mid \mathrm h_1, \mathrm h_2)$$

---

$(c)$ Total Probability again.  $$\mathsf E(T)=\mathsf P(\mathrm t_1)\,\mathsf E(T\mid \mathrm t_1)+\mathsf P(\mathrm h_1)\,\mathsf E(T\mid \mathrm h_1)$$

Simplify the result to solve for $\mathsf E(T)$.